# Date format gets automatically changed while saving data in json format from Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am having datecolumn in dataframe like below

```
df.REFERENCE_DATE

0      2019-11-26
1      2019-11-27
2      2019-11-29
3      2019-11-30
4      2019-11-26

df.dtpes
REFERENCE_DATE         datetime64[ns]

df.to_json('date.json', orient='records')
```

When I am reading the file again this date format get changed into string.

```
df1=pd.read_json('date.json')
0       1574726400000
1       1574812800000
2       1574985600000
3       1575072000000

df1.dtypes
 REFERENCE_DATE         object
```

I want to have date field have same format throughout. How to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it back

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date,unit='ms')
Out[62]: 
0   2019-11-26
1   2019-11-27
2   2019-11-29
3   2019-11-30
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @ashokeapen since the to_json saves dates with ms resolution by default